# How to get a collection of Out Of Stock (including configurable) products

Tags: collection, magento-1, out-of-stock

In my magento i have "Display out of stock products" -> No. (i needed like this).
I want to create a page with all out of stock products.
I have everything working, but cannot find the correct collection.
The products that must be included are: simple products that are out of stock AND configurable products with all of their simple out of stock.

**Update Edit 1**
There is one more important note. The solution must use query and not a new collection.

e.g this is the current code for filtering on "bestseller"

```
$select->joinLeft(array('stats' => new Zend_Db_Expr("(SELECT stats.product_id AS product_id, SUM(stats.qty_ordered - IFNULL(stats.qty_canceled, 0)) AS qty_ordered".
                " FROM {$res->getTableName('sales/order_item')} AS stats".
                " INNER JOIN {$res->getTableName('sales/order')} AS o ON".
                " (o.entity_id = stats.order_id AND".
                " (o.created_at BETWEEN '{$from}' AND '{$to}'))  AND o.state NOT IN ('pending_payment', 'new', 'canceled') AND".
                $db->quoteInto(" o.store_id = ?", Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()).
                " GROUP BY stats.product_id)")),
                "stats.product_id = e.entity_id", array('cat_index_position' => new Zend_Db_Expr('-stats.qty_ordered')));

        $this->_condition = 'stats.qty_ordered > 0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to below:

```
$productDetails    = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id)
                      ->getProductCollection()
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productDetails->joinField('is_in_stock',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'is_in_stock',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'is_in_stock=0',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left');
```

Comment: I updated my question with one more requirement. Although your solution would not work, since the configurable products have "is_in_stock = 1", but i want the configurable that has ALL of the associated products, out of stock to be included (as out of stock).